# All users which email contains "@MyDomain"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Which query should I use in Microsoft Graph (latest version) to get all users which email contains a specific character sequence?

I.E:

```
users.Where( x => x.Contains( str));
```

emails that ends with a sequence are still acceptable, but the first way is preferred.

```
users.Where( x => x.EndsWith( str));
```

It is preferrable to get as response a Json with an array of users rather than querying each one individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft [does not support `contains`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter-parameter), nor does it support LINQ style queries. As result, it isn't possible to filter `user` resources based on a given SMTP domain. It's also possible for a user to have more than one email address associated with the record (`userPrincipalName`, `mail`, `proxyAddresses[]`).

Your best bet would be to pull down the `user` records with the relevant properties and process them offline:

```
/v1.0/users/?$select=id,displayName,userPrincipalName,Mail,proxyAddresses
```

If this is something you need to do regularly, you could store them and [use `/delta` queries](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_users) to pull down only records that have changed to keep the two in sync:

```
/v1.0/users/delta?$select=id,displayName,userPrincipalName,Mail,proxyAddresses
```